# <body> content not sticking to the right edge in browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

One of the sites I'm designing breaks like this, when I resize it. Why doesn't it stick to browser's edges? How can I accomplish this?

[image: Detached right edge]

I used [CSS Layout Generator](http://csslayoutgenerator.com/) to generate the layout initially. I used the liquid layout option since I wanted to make my site responsive.

Within the `<body>` there's a wrapper `<div>` which is styled like so:

```
min-width: 320px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
```

The `wrapper` contains all the `header`, `middle-section` and `footer` which inherits from the wrapper's width. They have the `max-width` set to **1200px** and is **centered**.

Comment: Try setting `min-width: 100%;`.

Comment: is it possible that the wrapper is fitting the window but exceeding the max width of the header, middle-section, and footer? Try commenting those out and see.

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow-x: hidden` on the `html` element?

Comment: Since you have a horizontal scroll bar, it is likely that you aren't taking into account your margins somewhere.  Does the body (or any of the other parent elements) still have margins on it?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I'm trying to have a `max-width` of 1200px on the header and footer and the middle section. The middle section elements are divided in two columns, one floated to left another to the right.
None of them has fixed-width though...

Comment: @Asad The wrapper's width is set to 100% but the header and footers have max-widths of 1200px, cuz I wanna have them centered.

Comment: @Ana Is that a hack? I'm not sure if its done on responsive sites...
I did try it out though... didn't work!

Comment: @cimmanon Parent elements don't have margins on them, margins are only present on the child elements like `<p>`, `<nav>`, etc.

Comment: You want them to be centered and not touch the border, but also to touch the border?

Comment: @Asad -__- NO! I want it to be kinda like... say... stackoverflow's header and footer. They stretch across the page.. but they are still centered.

Comment: but they do not need to be centered if they are full width, and they DEFINITELY can't have a max width if they are to unconditionally touch both borders. See the jsfiddle I have provided. I believe you want to center their contents, for which you will need to apply css to their contents.

Comment: @maxxon15 but `body` *does* have margins on it by default.  Until you provide some code, everyone is just playing guessing games.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the User Agent styles for the left and right padding on `body`:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Then kindly put together a Fiddle of your problem.

Comment: @maxxon15 that won't actually reset the whole css. Take a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PrsHt/) fiddle. If you change the selector `.incorrectruledisabled` to `.incorrectrule`, you should see the results you are getting in your attached image.

You can't give something an upper limit on its width and also expect it to occupy the full width unconditionally. Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your question.

EDIT: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PrsHt/2/) is an example where the **contents** of the header, middle and footer are centered, using text-align, but they themselves are not.